Detect Shadow Tweak on iOS and prevent bypassing the jailbreak detection
What is the best way to detect the shadow tweak programmatically in jailbreaked iOS devices to prevent access an app?
We have tried adding file check in the directory.
"/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Shadow.dylib",
"/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Shadow.plist"

How do you expect to win against something that can patch out your code?
